# Rails conditional unless not working as intended

Tags: ruby-on-rails, conditional-statements

I have a rails application, and in my application controller, I have the following code:

```
redirect_to :login unless @current_user = User.find_by_uid(session[:cas_user])
@current_user.syncUserRoles
```

So, this is supposed to redirect them to log in unless it successfully finds their user account. However, it was still going to the next line even if @current_user returned nil.
So, I modified the code to the following:

```
@current_user = User.find_by_uid(session[:cas_user])
redirect_to :login unless @current_user.present?
@current_user.syncUserRoles
```

However, it would ignore the inline unless on line 2 and error out with a nilClass error on line 3. I had to finally resort to a full blown if else statement, but I'd like to know what I was doing wrong.

```
if @current_user.present?
    @current_user.syncUserRoles
else
    redirect_to :login
end //This works as intended
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The confusion here is in how `redirect_to` works, not `unless`. `redirect_to` just sets a `302 Moved` header, it won't return from your action. So the next line will still execute (your `@current_user.syncUserRoles` line), and when it does render, it will have the 302 status code set.

Putting it in a sole `else` branch, as you've discovered, is one way to avoid execution of that line.

Answer (score 2):

redirect_to doesn't stop code execution in a method. Call return to make sure you stop the code execution :

```
(redirect_to :login && return) unless @current_user = User.find_by_uid(session[:cas_user])
```

Does it work like this?

Comment: It works! However for some reason, once it comes back and runs up against that same piece of code, it does not set @current_user, even though at that point the user would exist. But thanks, I was unaware of that (too used to PHP I guess).

Comment: Double check that both `session[:cas_user]` and `User.find_by_uid(session[:cas_user])` are what you think they are ...  one of them has to be nil or may contain a wrong value